# How to access Images in folder in Express and not downloading them

Tags: express

```
app.use("/uploads", express.static("./server/uploads"));
```

Everytime I access *http://localhost:4500/uploads/16562754008013gncm1.jfif* , it automatically downloads

```
-index.js
-server
----uploads
-------16562754008013gncm1.jfif
```

[Folder Structure in Express](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPGTP.png)

Comment: When the client sends a GET for a URL that contains any files in your `./server/uploads` folder, the ENTIRE point of that request is to fetch the image which means the server sends it to the client per the line of Express middleware that you show.  What else are you expecting it to do?

Comment: It occurs to me that part of your problem might be that `.jfif` is perhaps a file extension that Express and the browser don't know and recognize so the only thing a browser knows to do with it is offer a download dialog in the browser.  If Express recognizes the file extension, it will set the appropriate content-type.  If not, it won't.  You can fix that by either giving the file a file extension that is generally known that corresponds to its actual type or you can manually override and set the content-type (if that content-type is something that the browser recognizes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be that part of your problem is that `.jfif` is perhaps a file extension that Express and the browser don't know and recognize so the only thing a browser knows to do with it is offer a download dialog in the browser.   You can verify this by looking in the network tab of the Chrome/Edge or Firefix inspector and look at what the content-type is set to when the response comes back from the server.

If Express recognizes the file extension, it will set the appropriate content-type. And, if the browser recognizes the content-type, it will treat it appropriately.  If not, Express will set a generic content-type and the browser won't know what to do with it other than offering a download dialog.

You can fix that by either giving the file a file extension that is generally known that corresponds to its actual type or you can manually override and set the content-type (if that content-type is something that the browser recognizes).